# Enviar formulario al mail, Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, reactjs

estoy dando mis primeros pasos con react y el mundo del front-end, me encuentro realizando  una pagina de contacto con react, y estuve leyendo documentación, viendo pero y no encuentro como hacer para que me envié el formulario a hacer click en el button.

````
  return (
     <section className="container Contacto espacio">

           <form
             onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
             method="POSt"
             name="fcontacto"
             id="fcontacto"
           >
             <div className="row">
               <div className="col-md-6">
                 <div className="form-group">
                   <label>Tu Nombre</label>
                   <input
                     type="text"
                     className="form-control"
                     id="name"
                     onChange={(e) =>
                       this.setState({ inputName: e.target.value })
                     }

                     ref={(inputElement) => (this.inputName = inputElement)}
                     value={this.state.inputName}
                   />
                 </div>
                </div>
             <button class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar">
               ENVIAR
             </button>

             <div id="respuesta"></div>
           </form>


     </section>
   );

}```
````

Comment: ¿El botón es lo que no funciona o es el código que tienes dentro de handleSubmit lo que no funciona?

Comment: el handle submit funciona, lo que no se es como hacer que envie eso que guarda por mail directamente,

Comment: Necesitarás conectarlo con el backend o bien puedes usar el paquete npm https://www.emailjs.com/ para enviarlo directamente desde React

Comment: yo uso Firebase, lo mando directo a la base de datos? y eso me lo envia ami?